# Dealing with data in python

Tags: python, regex, list

Here is the list:

```
keyWord = ['gold', 'diamond', 'wood']
```

And,the score's text file include detail like below. For example, the name of text file is point.txt

```
diamond 1
copper 2
wood 3
gold 4
```

In text file, the space between word and number is divided by tab.

I want to get a total point of keyword list using this score's text file with python.

My code goes like this...

```
import re
open_file = open("point.txt")

points = {}
for line in open_file:
    item, score = line.split("\t")
    points[item] = int(score)
    if item == re.findall('[\w\']+', keyWord):
```

I don't know how to write a code to get a total point with regular expression. (I think the 'IF' sentence has a fault.)

I'll waiting your great help.

Comment: points[item] not points(item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> lis = ['gold', 'diamond', 'wood']
>>> points = dict.fromkeys(lis,0)     #create a dict from the list with initial value as 0
>>> with open("abc") as f:            #use with context manger to open filees
...     for line in f: 
...         key,val = line.split()   # no need of regex     
...         if key in points:        #if key is present in points then increment it's value
...             points[key] += int(val)   #use points[key] syntax to access a dict
...             
>>> points
{'gold': 4, 'wood': 3, 'diamond': 1}
```

Comment: If I want to read lis from file, how can I get a total of each line? if there are lis file include 20 line of lists?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, similar to Ashwini's answer:

```
from collections import defaultdict

points = defaultdict(int)

with open('abc.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            key, val = line.split()
            points[key.strip()] += int(val.strip())

# If your keywords file is like this:
# diamond
# gold
# wood
# Then you can use the below snippet to read the keywords:
with open('keywords.txt') as f:
    keywords = list(line for line in f if line.strip())

# If your keywords file is like this:
# diamond, gold, wood
# silver, platinum, water
# Then use the below snippet:

keywords = []
with open('keywords.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
           for keyword in line.split(','):
                keywords.append(keyword.strip())

for i in keywords:
    print("{} {}".format(i,points.get(i,0)))
```

Comment: Thank you for advice! It will take a little time to understand cause there is  new concept to me.

Comment: If I want to read keyword list from file like score's txt file in my post. How can I get a total point of each line? For example, keyword list thing like : ['gold' ,'diamond', 'wood'] , ['copper', 'plastic','rubber'], .... If there are 20 lines of list in keyword list file..... ?